# What is the sarcastic English word to describe a highly paid job?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the sarcastic English word to describe a highly paid job but with no responsibilities?

Answer (score 1):

"Sinecure" is the most common term. From Merriam-Webster:

> 1: an office or position that requires little or no work and that usually provides an income
>
> 2 archaic : an ecclesiastical benefice without cure of souls

I like that second meaning because it explains the word's etymology, from the Latin *sine cura*, or *without cure*. A church duty that does not help souls, a job that produces no work. It makes sense.

Comment: I will note that this answer doesn't really meet the specification for a "sarcastic" term.

Comment: True, except insofar as we commonly use the term sarcastically.